# Is it possible to run (and view) two apps simultaneously?

Tags: android, simultaneous

I have some questions about android development.
I have googled around, but cannot seem to find any answers to my questions.

1. Is it possible to display google maps in a widget?
2. Is it possible to run (and view) two apps simultaneously?
3. Is it possible to run an App within an App?

Comment: By widget, do you mean a homescreen widget or just a widget like a linearlayout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Is it possible to display google maps in a widget?
   **Yes**
2. Is it possible to run (and view) two apps simultaneously? **No**
3. Is it possible to run an App within an App? **You can launch an app, from another app. But you can't run an app inside another. Well... you could try playing with an ActivityGroup and get a View reference of the inner app you want to run, and then render that View... but I think it is nonsense**

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer.
Regarding displaying google maps in a widget. Do you mean static google maps, or the actual MapView?