# Android Battery Application

Tags: eclipse, sdk

Hi Good day I am currently working on my thesis and one of my objective is to show the power consumption of a running application.
Here's the scenario for example I'm playing angry birds and what my thesis should do is to show the power consumption ON THE SAME SCREEN (while PLAYING the said application) Is that possible? Can anyone help me on how to develop such application? If its not can you please give me a link that would explain that it is impossible? Because my professor would only believe my claim if I got an answer from a credible and reliable source.

I hope you guys can help me with this. I'm a newbie in android programming and I really need your help so bad..
Thank you so much XoXo :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar question already answered: [Is it possible to run (and view) two apps simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088263/is-it-possible-to-run-and-view-two-apps-simultaneously)

It doesn't appear so.  [This third-party software](http://hothardware.com/News/Ixonos-Creates-MultiWindow-Solution-For-Android/) is the closest I've seen to something like that, but it will likely affect your power consumption data.

Comment: Thank you for a helpful answer but I'm thinking of developing an application that I mean doesn't need a third party application to view the power consumption I need to include it in the application that I'm developing not just in the widget .. thank you so much I appreciate it. :)